# Defining another Cache-Control than the set cache timeout in Python / Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-cache

I'd like to cache my view as follows:

```
@cache_page(10)
def myview:
    return HttpResponse('content')
```

This automatically caches my view for 10 seconds and automatically sets Cache-Control/Expire header as well. I'd like to cache my view for only 10 seconds but have a max-age of 3600 seconds.

Tried it for example this way:

```
@cache_page(10)
def myview:
    response = HttpResponse('content')
    patch_response_headers(response, 3600)
```

or this way:

```
@cache_page(10)
def myview:
    response = HttpResponse('content')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=3600'
```

But when specifying one of those within my Django-View it caches the view for 3600 seconds and not 10 seconds. Also tried decorators like 'cache_control' but nothing helps.

Is there a solution for this problem? I'm using Django 1.4.1.

Don't know if it is relavent, my activated middleware classes are

- django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware
- django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware
- django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware
- django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware
- django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
- django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware

I've activated the ConditionalGetMiddleware to make sure a 304 will be sent depending on the last-modified header.

Thanks a lot!

Holger